# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'XX' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I try to use this command

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Customers ON
Insert into Customers(CustomerID,[Guest Name],Gender,Country,HomePhone,Address)
Values(1,'amro','male','sudan','098766512','sudan');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Customers Off
```

but i doesn't works with me, what shall i do else

Comment: You sure you are executing these whole statement in a single batch?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement will work. check this example.

```
BEGIN TRAN

Create TABLE Customers (CustomerID int identity(1,1), [Guest name] varchar(100), Gender varchar(10), country varchar(50),homephone varchar(50) , address varchar(50) )


Insert into Customers([Guest Name],Gender,Country,HomePhone,Address)
Values('amro','male','sudan','098766512','sudan');


select * from Customers


SET IDENTITY_INSERT Customers ON
Insert into Customers(CustomerID,[Guest Name],Gender,Country,HomePhone,Address)
Values(1,'amro','male','sudan','098766512','sudan');

Insert into Customers(CustomerID,[Guest Name],Gender,Country,HomePhone,Address)
Values(22,'amro','male','sudan','098766512','sudan');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Customers OFF

select * from Customers

ROLLBACK
```